# How is it possible that $SystemMemory is set to zero?

Tags: memory, system-variables

For one of my Windows machines (*Mathematica* 12.x.x, only one of them) apparently `$SystemMemory` returns 0 (zero). I'm unable to do anything with that, since `Attributes[$SystemMemory]` are both `Protected` and `Locked`. Some functions do not work because of that, `NetTrain` in particular. Any solutions/workarounds?

Comment: Can you set it to a different value? How did you come upon this? What happens in a fresh kernel? Which version of Mathematica is it? (The X’s are important for figuring this out, can you, please, include them?) I also removed the bugs tag as this is not yet a confirmed bug. Did you report this to wolfram tech support?

Comment: What does `systeminfo |find "Memory"` return from a windows command prompt?

Comment: Can you use `Block` to assign a value for the calls that fail?

Comment: @ciao Total Physical Memory:     32 699 MB
Available Physical Memory: 22 830 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  37 563 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 25 329 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    12 234 MB

Comment: @CATrevillian I'm unable to change it. I've filled bug report but no answer so far. I found this trying some examples from NetTrain manual resulting with error: NetInitialize::tnsrmaxsz: Cannot create an array of dimensions 32*2 because it would consume 256.0 bytes, which is ComplexInfinity% of total system memory. Problem was in 12.2, but after very recent upgrade to 12.3 still the same problem.

Comment: @mikado Nope: Block::lockt: Cannot localize locked symbol `$SystemMemory` in assignment `$SystemMemory=1000000 from local variable specification {$SystemMemory=1000000}`.

Comment: I probably would try a reinstallation and/or ask WRI support for a solution. I don't think it is likely that someone here can help you with this, but maybe you are lucky...